# How do I get Keys and where are the corresponding Chests?

Tags: destiny

On the Dreadnaught, I have come across some chests that says "*Requires Key of .....*" to be able to open them.

During a fight near the first spawn point, I acquired a Key of Akka but have yet to find where the chest is located. Will it be on the Dreadnaught or do I have to go to another location?

This leads me to several questions regarding these keys/chests:

- How many keys are there?
- Are all of the keys/chests obtained on the Dreadnaught?
- Do these chests contain unique items? Legendary items? Exotic items?
- Which monsters drop the keys?
- Do you get anything special for opening all of the chests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 9 keys in total, which open 9 different chests. There are 4 other special chests which can be opened via other means, but I won't go into those here.

All chests are located on the Dreadnaught and so is the means of obtaining the keys.

The first chest you open (doesn't matter which of the 9) will reward a Calcified Fragment. They also reward Wormspore, Eris Morn reputation and can contain Rare and Legendary Engrams.

Keys can be obtained via the following method:

- First you need a Wormsinger Rune. These can drop from Hive Knights and Wizards on the Dreadnaught (and maybe by other means).
- In the Hull Breach, in one of the caves is a Hive machine which you can insert the Wormsinger Rune. It is in the same room as the Chest of Ur.
- Once the Wormsinger Rune has been inserted, outside the cave, by the opening of the Cabals crashed ship, Hive will start to spawn.
- Killing these will eventually cause a named Ogre to spawn and on death can drop a Wormfeeder Rune.
- It doesn't have to be spawned by you to have a chance at a Wormfeeder Rune, so you can hang around the Hull Breach area hoping that someone else will spawn the ogre.
- The Wormfeeder Rune requires charging and in order to do so, you have to kill 50 enemies on the Dreadnaught without dying.
- Once complete, the rune will transform into one of the 9 keys, which appears to be completely random.

You don't get anything special for opening them all.

There is a very good post on Reddit for these, plus the other 4 chests I mentioned. Can find it [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/3ldaqw/all_dreadnaught_chests_guide_text_and_video/).

Comment: Very nice answer. There is a little missing though ;)

Comment: @TravisJ I believe you only get a Calcified Fragment the first time you open any of the 9 chests (so you don't really get anything special for opening all the chests, just one). Touch of Malice does look awesome though :)

Comment: All of the Calcified Fragments come from unique spots. So you can only get one from each place. This set of chests has one fragment per chest.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in @Lyrical's answer is good, but there is a little bit missing.

"Calcified Fragment" will drop from these chests.

- Do you get anything special for opening all of the chests?

Not directly. However, the Calcified Fragment set is important. Each one that you obtain will give you a grimoire card. There are 50 of these fragments, and when you are on the destinations screen for Saturn you can see your progress. All of the fragments are on the dreadnaught in one place or another.

Each chest contains one of these fragments. Obtaining 45 of them will allow you to start a quest to get the exotic scout rifle http://www.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Touch_of_Malice . A high quality guardian has a guide here to all of the fragments https://www.vg247.com/2015/09/28/destiny-the-taken-king-calcified-fragments-locations-guide/ .